# security settings for graph databases

Tags: nosql, neo4j, graph-databases

Relational Databases are able to set permissions for users to insert, update, delete, etc by schema or table (e.g. I can allow bob CRUD access to table someschema.XYZ but only allow read access to someschema.FooBar and no access to schema ABC)

Graph databases do not have predefined schemas but have an arbitrary set of node types. Is it possible to set restrictions on a graph database for what a user can access like you do for relational databases or does this granularity not exist in graph databases due to it's nature?

I am specifically looking at Neo4j but if this exists in other examples, then I would like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j allows you to implement your own [SecurityRules](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules). A SecurityRule acts similar to a servlet filter, every request is evaluated with the SecurityRule.

However you have to implement the logic on your own which gives great flexibility but might also cause a serious amount of work.